# Show alert message on HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm New at PHP, I want to ask about my problem. I have a code for insert function and for check the duplicate data. But on my code can't show a message if there're a duplicate data. But the query for checking double data is work., and i want to show my message duplicate data on master_toko.php after section class content. Please Help me for this problem

crudAction.php

```
<?php
    
    function runQuery($db, $query, $queryType) {
    
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        if(!empty(mysqli_error($db))) {
            return [
                'error' => true,
                'message' => mysqli_error($db)
            ];
        }
            
            return [
                'error' => false,
                'message' => getMessage($queryType)
            ];
    }
    
    function buildInsertQuery($tableName, $data) {
    
        $tableColumns = [];
        $insertValues = [];
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            array_push($tableColumns, $key);
            array_push($insertValues, $value);
        }
    
        $columns = "(`" . implode("`,`", $tableColumns) . "`)";
        $values = "('" . implode("','", $insertValues) . "')";
        $query = "INSERT INTO `$tableName` ". $columns . " VALUES " . $values ." ";
        
        return $query ?? false;
    }
    
    
    function getMessage($queryType) {
        $messages = [
            'insert' => 'Data has been succesfuly added',
            'delete' => 'Data has been succesfuly deleted',
            'dataDouble' => 'Data Ada yang Dobel'
        ];  
    
        return $messages[$queryType];
    }
    
    function getLastID() {
        return mysqli_insert_id();
    }
    ?>
```

formAction.php

```
<?php
    
    $actionObject = $_REQUEST['actionObject'] ?? '';
    $actionType = $_REQUEST['actionType'] ?? '';
    
    include $actionObject .'Crud.php';
    include 'config.php';
    
    function getTableName($actionObject) 
    {
      $tableMapping = [
        'toko' => 'master_toko'

      ];
        return $tableMapping[$actionObject];
    }
    
    $db = getDBConnection();
    $tableName = getTableName($actionObject);
    
    switch($actionType):
      case 'insert' : $result = insertData($db, $tableName);
        break;
      case 'delete' : $result = deleteData($db, $tableName);
        break;
      case 'update' : $result = updateData($db, $tableName);
        break;
    endswitch;
    
    if (!$result['error']) {
        header('location: ' . $_REQUEST['pageReferrer'] . '&error=false&message=' . $result['message']);
    } else {
        header('location: ' . $_REQUEST['pageReferrer'] . '&error=true&message=' . $result['message']);
    }
    
    
    
    
    ?>
```

tokoCrud.php

````
 ```
<?php
        include ('crudAction.php');
        
        function insertData($db, $tableName) {

            $redirect_url = 'http://localhost/city/?page=store&error=false&message=';
            $data = [
                'id_ot' => ' ',
                'nama_ot' => $_POST['namaToko'],
                'alamat_ot' => $_POST['alamatToko'],
                'status_ot' => '1'
            ];
    
            if(!isDataTokoExist($db, $namaToko)) {
                $query = buildInsertQuery($tableName, $data);
                
                return runQuery($db, $query, 'insert');
            }
            else {
                return runQuery($db, $query, 'dataDouble');
            }
            
        }

        function isDataTokoExist($db, $namaToko) {
            $namaToko = $_POST['namaToko'];
            $query = "SELECT * FROM master_toko WHERE nama_ot = '$namaToko'";
            $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
            
        }

    ?>
```
````

messageBox.php

````
```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['error']) && isset($_GET['message'])) {
        $error = $_GET['error'];
        $message = $_GET['message'];
        $messageClass = $error === 'false' ? 'error-message' : 'success-message';
    ?>

        <div class ="message <?php echo $messageClass; ?>">
            <?php echo $message; ?>
        </div>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
```
````

master_toko.php

````
```
<?php
  require "partial/header.php";
  require "partial/sidebar.php";
  // include 'messageBox.php';
 ?>
  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->

    <section class="content-header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1>Master Toko</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
              <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Master Toko</li>
            </ol>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
    <?php include 'library/services/messageBox.php'; 
                ?>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title">Data Toko</h3>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success float-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modalBesar">Tambah Data</button>
              </div>
            <!-- Bagian Form Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade modalBesar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Tambah Toko</h4>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <form method = "post" action = "library/services/formAction.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="pageReferrer" value="http://localhost/city/?page=store" >
                <input type="hidden" name="actionObject" value="toko" >
                <input type="hidden" name="actionType" value="insert" >
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Nama Toko</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="namaToko" placeholder="Masukkan Nama Toko" name="namaToko" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Alamat Toko</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="alamatToko" placeholder="Masukkan Nama Toko" name="alamatToko" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Submit</button>
              </div>
                </form>
              </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Akhir Bagian Modal -->

            

              <!-- /.card-header -->
              <div class="card-body">
                <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>No</th>
                    <th>Toko</th>
                    <th>Alamat</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Opsi</th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
              <!-- /.card-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.card -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.col -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
    
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
  <?php require "partial/footer.php"; ?>




```
````

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `isDataTokoExist()` function doesn't `return` a value, so referencing it in a conditional will always yield `NULL`, regardless of whatever calculations it's doing. You want to `return` the result of your calculation:

```
function isDataTokoExist($db, $namaToko) {
    if (<some calculation to determine if the data exists>) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Also note, you generally don't want to rely on the output of a SELECT query to avoid inserting duplicates. In a multi-user system, another process could insert into the database between the time when your SELECT runs and your subsequent INSERT runs, and then you'll get duplicates. Instead, create a UNIQUE constraint on the field in question and then verify that your INSERT succeeded.

And, your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Instead of building queries with string concatenation, always use [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) with [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). See [**this page**](https://phptherightway.com/#databases) and [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for some good examples.